# AMD CPU with dedicated GPU and the onboard VGA port

Tags: cpu, vga

I am wondering why my motherboard has a VGA port, if my AMD CPU(not APU) is not capable of graphics processing(or so I believe).

What will happen if I use the VGA port? 
Will there be a display at all?
Is it necessary for my AMD R7 260x graphics card?

Specs: 
AMD FX 6300

MSI 970A-G46 Motherboard

AMD R7 260x

Comment: Looking at the technical specification of your mobo shows a serial port on the back but no vga port. Have you checked how many pins are in there?  http://www.msi.com/product/mb/970A-G46.html#?div=Detail

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, it's a serial port. Just did some research and VGA has 15 pins and mine has 9 pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motherboards have onboard video, it is slow and performs slowly but it works.

Your R7 260x will be used, not the onboard if you enable the card and plug the monitor into the R7, the onboard is there for buyers who do not need accelerated graphics.

Comment: Thanks :D Is it part of the chipset?

Comment: The onboard video is, yes. With an APU it is integrated on the CPU instead and Intel is going to do something similar in Xeons and physics in the near future.

Answer (score -1):

The chipset of your mobo probably has an integrated gpu, not anything serious, just for a default gpu. If your computing doent require graphics or compute from gpu, then this is a good deal because there is no neeed for an external gpu!

Comment: This really should have been a comment since it doesn't really answer the author's question.